# How do we measure number of possible encryptions in One Time Pad

Tags: encryption, one-time-pad, brute-force-attack

trying to brute force a specific length of ciphered pad, how do we measure the total number of possible encryptions in One Time Pad

Comment: Brute force the One Time Pad?! Have a nice snipe hunt. Hint: if the pad has length $n$ bits, how many values can it take?

Comment: I can do it in 3 steps. 1) Find the person who encrypted the message. 2) Beat them with a [rubber hose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber-hose_cryptanalysis) until they tell you the key. 3) Profit.

Comment: @mikeazo I doubt they'll remember the key.

Comment: @Aleph, but they will tell you where the key is and / or how to recover it!

Comment: @AKC **The probability of an attack failure scales proportional to the length of ciphertext.** See, without human error like (eg) “key reuse”, you’re facing so called “perfect secrecy” – you can’t gain any usable information about the plaintext. Assuming you don’t know any plaintext either, it’s practically a waste of time unless you’re really, really lucky guessing parts of the key… which has near-to-perfect randomness if OTP has been applied correctly. *(PS: Always do some research before asking; including searching Crypto.SE. We have 130+ [tag:one-time-pad] related questions with answers!)*